# Simple Authentication for aspnet web api core

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am devloping a web api in .net core framework. Ui is in angularjs. I have multiple users with different roles in the system. What is the simple and best authentication for this web api?

Tried to do Identity server4 but i dont need redirection to single sign on so i don't really need that complex implementation. All i want is to secure the api so that non-logged in/ anonymous users cannot access it.

Things i have tried so far are "Cookie middleware without aspnet identity". Works little bit but the real problem is, i am not sure how to return cookie from api and pass it back from ui.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

I looked online but most of the articles are for MVC. Since this is a web api, i need to pass back something to the caller so that they can pass it back to the api which will be authenticated.

Hope it makes sense.

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good article [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) which goes into great details about authenticaton and authorization. The article also explains how you can apply authentication to the whole API, to a controller, to a single method etc. All the code for the tutorial is on CodePlex [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/BasicAuthentication/BasicAuthentication/Filters/BasicAuthenticationAttribute.cs) and I am copying the one for basic authentication below:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using BasicAuthentication.Results;

namespace BasicAuthentication.Filters
{
    public abstract class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {
        public string Realm { get; set; }

        public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

            if (authorization == null)
            {
                // No authentication was attempted (for this authentication method).
                // Do not set either Principal (which would indicate success) or ErrorResult (indicating an error).
                return;
            }

            if (authorization.Scheme != "Basic")
            {
                // No authentication was attempted (for this authentication method).
                // Do not set either Principal (which would indicate success) or ErrorResult (indicating an error).
                return;
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
            {
                // Authentication was attempted but failed. Set ErrorResult to indicate an error.
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing credentials", request);
                return;
            }

            Tuple<string, string> userNameAndPasword = ExtractUserNameAndPassword(authorization.Parameter);

            if (userNameAndPasword == null)
            {
                // Authentication was attempted but failed. Set ErrorResult to indicate an error.
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid credentials", request);
                return;
            }

            string userName = userNameAndPasword.Item1;
            string password = userNameAndPasword.Item2;

            IPrincipal principal = await AuthenticateAsync(userName, password, cancellationToken);

            if (principal == null)
            {
                // Authentication was attempted but failed. Set ErrorResult to indicate an error.
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid username or password", request);
            }
            else
            {
                // Authentication was attempted and succeeded. Set Principal to the authenticated user.
                context.Principal = principal;
            }
        }

        protected abstract Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        private static Tuple<string, string> ExtractUserNameAndPassword(string authorizationParameter)
        {
            byte[] credentialBytes;

            try
            {
                credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authorizationParameter);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // The currently approved HTTP 1.1 specification says characters here are ISO-8859-1.
            // However, the current draft updated specification for HTTP 1.1 indicates this encoding is infrequently
            // used in practice and defines behavior only for ASCII.
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
            // Make a writable copy of the encoding to enable setting a decoder fallback.
            encoding = (Encoding)encoding.Clone();
            // Fail on invalid bytes rather than silently replacing and continuing.
            encoding.DecoderFallback = DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback;
            string decodedCredentials;

            try
            {
                decodedCredentials = encoding.GetString(credentialBytes);
            }
            catch (DecoderFallbackException)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(decodedCredentials))
            {
                return null;
            }

            int colonIndex = decodedCredentials.IndexOf(':');

            if (colonIndex == -1)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string userName = decodedCredentials.Substring(0, colonIndex);
            string password = decodedCredentials.Substring(colonIndex + 1);
            return new Tuple<string, string>(userName, password);
        }

        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Challenge(context);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private void Challenge(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context)
        {
            string parameter;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Realm))
            {
                parameter = null;
            }
            else
            {
                // A correct implementation should verify that Realm does not contain a quote character unless properly
                // escaped (precededed by a backslash that is not itself escaped).
                parameter = "realm=\"" + Realm + "\"";
            }

            context.ChallengeWith("Basic", parameter);
        }

        public virtual bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Does that work with .net core framework as well??

Comment: I would give it a quick try if I were you and see if it does. I dont have .net core set up or i would have tried it out.

Comment: Thanks. I used Aspnet identity and works fine so far.

Comment: Outdated answer